# What does -fprofile-arcs linker option mean?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I want to have code covergage in my application, so in `premake.lua` I added the following:

```
if options["coverage"] then
    tinsert(package.buildoptions, {"-fprofile-arcs", "-ftest-coverage"})
    tinsert(package.links, "gcov") 
end
```

then I ran the following command:

```
premake --coverage --target gnu ; make
```

That did not work until I added the following :

```
 if options["coverage"] then
    tinsert(package.buildoptions, {"-fprofile-arcs", "-ftest-coverage"})
    tinsert(package.linkoptions, {"-fprofile-arcs"})
    tinsert(package.links, "gcov")
 end
```

Which was a solution posed on the Internet. My problem is that I found 0 documentation on this `-fprofile-arcs` linker flag... What does it do? and where is it documented?

Comment: you won't find anything in Google if your search query starts with `-`

Answer (score 5):

This option is not given to the linker. It is interpreted by the compiler driver(gcc, g++).

When compiling, this option is just passed to the compiler (cc1, cc1plus).

When linking, the effect of the options is that the compiler driver just includes the `-lgcov` on the linker command line.

Comment: Regardless of other possible ways to get `-lgcov` in the linker command line, `-fprofile-arcs` does just that when the compiler driver is invoked for linking.